# How do I use server garbage collection with dotnet fsi?

Tags: .net-core, f#, f#-interactive

I would like to use server garbage collection with dotnet fsi. How do I do this?

Garbage collection should be configurable via runtime settings referenced in these two sources:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/

I am using windows and the dotnet 5 preview sdk. `dotnet fsi` runs fine.

I made the following `fsi.runtimeconfig.json` file and placed it at `C:\Program Files\dotnet`:

```
{
   "runtimeOptions": {
      "configProperties": {
         "System.GC.Server": true
      }
   }
}
```

However, when I call `dotnet fsi --runtimeconfig fsi.runtimeconfig.json` I get the following error:

```
> dotnet fsi --runtimeconfig "fsi.runtimeconfig.json"


error FS0243: Unrecognized option: '--runtimeconfig'

Exception by fsi.exe:
System.Exception: Error creating evaluation session: StopProcessingExn None
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfModule.PrintFormatToStringThenFail@1639.Invoke(String message) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\printf.fs:line 1639
   at FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Shell.FsiCommandLineOptions..ctor(FsiEvaluationSessionHostConfig fsi, String[] argv, TcConfigBuilder tcConfigB, FsiConsoleOutput fsiConsoleOutput) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\fsi\fsi.fs:line 726
   at FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Shell.FsiEvaluationSession..ctor(FsiEvaluationSessionHostConfig fsi, String[] argv, TextReader inReader, TextWriter outWriter, TextWriter errorWriter, Boolean fsiCollectible, FSharpOption`1 legacyReferenceResolver) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\fsi\fsi.fs:line 2484
   at FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Shell.FsiEvaluationSession.Create(FsiEvaluationSessionHostConfig fsiConfig, String[] argv, TextReader inReader, TextWriter outWriter, TextWriter errorWriter, FSharpOption`1 collectible, FSharpOption`1 legacyReferenceResolver) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\fsi\fsi.fs:line 2825
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Sample.FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Main.evaluateSession(String[] argv) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\fsi\fsimain.fs:line 269
```

If I omit the runtime config option, fsi starts, but `System.Runtime.GCSettings.IsServerGC` is `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MacOs/linux:
You need to change *dotnet.runtimeconfig.json*. Located in the latest dotnet SDK version e.g. */usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.301*.

For Windows:
You need to change *fsi.runtimeconfig.json* which is located in the Fsharp folder for the latest SDK version e.g. *C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100-preview.4.20258.7\FSharp*

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp3.1",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "3.1.5"
    },
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
   }
  }
}
```

dotnet fsi

```
> System.Runtime.GCSettings.IsServerGC;;
val it : bool = true
```

Comment: Ok, this helped. I found the correct file to change **on Windows**, the file that needs to be changed (adjusting for sdk version) is at `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100-preview.4.20258.7\FSharp\fsi.runtimeconfig.json`. Are you sure that it is dotnet.runtimeconfig.json on MacOS and not the equivalent fsi.runtimeconfig on MacOS?

Comment: @nh2 it depends how you run fsi.  If you run dotnet fsi then  it's dotnet.runtimeconfig.json.  There's an fsi.runtimeconfig.json but this is for a fsi.exe and .exes don't work in linux.

Comment: Ok, must be a windows difference. I run dotnet fsi from windows, but it uses fsi.runtimeconfig.json because that calls fsi.exe apparently.  Thanks for your help! Do you want to update your answer to point to the location on windows?

Comment: for the mac users, make changes in `/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.202/FSharp/fsi.runtimeconfig.json`, even if run `dotnet fsi`. Editing `dotnet.runtimeconfig.json` did it not though